# Laravel 404 Error on production

Tags: php, laravel

I created a route file with the following structure:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '46.101.255.245', 'namespace' => 'API'], function() {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'v1'], function() {

        Route::get('/aeds', 'APIAEDController@index');
    });
});
```

and a controller containing the method:

```
public function index() {
    return "OK";
}
```

When I call the address:

`46.101.255.245/v1/aeds`

I get a 404. On my local machine the same code runs smoothly. Do I need to change the route file?

The NGINX config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/mfserver/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name 46.101.255.245;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

When I just call the server IP I at least get the routing error which tells me, that laravel is working.

Comment: is `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server? is `AllowOverride` set to `All`

Comment: I am using nginx. Does this influence?

Comment: Can you show us your nginx config for this website?

Comment: I edited the question including the config

Comment: Got it! I edited the location section to try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;